# correct result, poor performance

Tags: java

I need suggestions on how to improve this code. Each value of array A passed in as argument represent the index of a counter to be incremented, but if this value is greater than N then the counter with the highest value is to be identified and its value assigned to every other counter. This code passed all test cases for correctness, but only 40% for performance.

```
package com.sample;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class ConsecOperations {
    
    public int[] executeAll(int N, int[] A) {
        
        int[] counters = new int[N];
        int toAdd = 0;
        //iterate though A
        //perform appropriate operation on each iteration
        for(int a = 0; a < A.length; a++) {
            
            if(A[a] > N ) {
                int maxValue = getMax(counters);
                
                
                for(int b = 0; b < counters.length; b++) {
                    counters[b] = maxValue; 
                }
                
                
            } else {
                ++counters[A[a] - 1];
            }
        }
        
        return counters;
    }
    
    public int getMax(int[] array) {
        
        int max = 0;
        
        for( int x : array ) {
            if( x > max ) {
                max = x;
            }
        }
        
        System.out.println("Generated max: " + max);
        return max;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConsecOperations c = new ConsecOperations();
        int[] intArray = {3,4,4,6,1,4,4};
        int[] result = c.executeAll(5, intArray);
        for(int z : result) {
            System.out.print(z + ",\t");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Go to [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
static int[] executeAll(int N, int[] A) {
    int[] counters = new int[N];
    int maxValue = 0;
    for (int a : A) {
        if (a > N)
            Arrays.fill(counters, maxValue);
        else
            maxValue = Math.max(maxValue, ++counters[a - 1]);
    }
    return counters;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] intArray = {3, 4, 4, 6, 1, 4, 4};
    int[] result = executeAll(5, intArray);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
}
```

output:

```
[3, 2, 2, 4, 2]
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This improved the performance to 60%. Thanks